# Help with an IF and SED to replace \n

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a filename variable that *sometimes* gets set as:

```
attachment; 
JobRunStatisticsReport_20150122.zip
```

In the File Manager window, it looks like this:

[image]

I need help coming up with an IF statement that says:

IF $filename contains 'attachment; \n'
then

and then help with a SED that looks for that new line character (\n) and replaces that and everything before it with nothing.

Can anyone lend a quick hand please?

Comment: Why `sed` specifically? it doesn't naturally deal with multi-line input, and if you already have the name in a shell variable why not try something bash-based like `"${var#*$'\n'}"`?

Comment: I suppose you tried `sed 's/.*\\n//g'` and `sed 's/.*\\r//g'` ?

Comment: it has something to do with characters that are not seen by my terminal window when I just echo $filename .   
If I type this:   
> for k in $(ls "$dec"); do
> echo $k
> done
>
>attachment; 
>JobRunStatisticsReport_20150122.zip
>

But if I just echo $filename, I get:

> echo $filename
> JobRunStatisticsReport_20150122.zip


I know it doesn't copy out well here, but just echoing the value gives the correct name.  But when my script hit it, it grabs the attachment; part of it.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the relevant portion of your script, as it appears you are doing some questionable things: to start, don't use `for k in $(ls "$dec")` as it will *word split* - use `for k in "$dec"/*` instead, and remember to also quote k when you use it `"$k"`.

Answer (score 2):

Your filename actually contains both a carriage return and a newline. bash parameter expansion can handle this:

```
$ filename=$'attachment;\r\nJobRunStatisticsReport_20150122.zip'
$ echo "$filename"
attachment;
JobRunStatisticsReport_20150122.zip
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo "${filename##attachment;*([[:space:]])}"
JobRunStatisticsReport_20150122.zip
```

Does not affect "normal" filenames:

```
$ filename="no attachment here"
$ echo "${filename##attachment;*([[:space:]])}"
no attachment here
```